# Hadoop Connection Refused, High Availibiloty Name Node Configuration on Docker

Tags: docker, hadoop

I am currently configuring hadoop for namenode HA using the Quorum Journal Manager. I have 3 Journalnodes. Below are my configurations:
hdfs-site.xml:

```
    <configuration>

<property>
  <name>dfs.nameservices</name>
  <value>cluster</value>
  <description>
    Comma-separated list of nameservices.
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.ha.namenodes.cluster</name>
  <value>nn1,nn2</value>
  <description>
  </description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.cluster.nn1</name>
  <value>namenode1:8020</value>
  <description>
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.cluster.nn2</name>
  <value>namenode2:8020</value>
  <description>
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.cluster.nn1</name>
  <value>namenode1:50070</value>
  <description>
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.cluster.nn2</name>
  <value>namenode2:50070</value>
  <description>
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir</name>
  <value>qjournal://journalnode1:8485;journalnode2:8485;journalnode3:8485/cluster</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider</name>
  <value></value>
  <description>
    The prefix (plus a required nameservice ID) for the class name of the
    configured Failover proxy provider for the host.  For more detailed
    information, please consult the "Configuration Details" section of
    the HDFS High Availability documentation.
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.ha.fencing.methods</name>
  <value>shell(/bin/true)</value>
</property>

    <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>/hadoop_data/namenode</value>
    <description>NameNode directory for storing namespace and transaction logs</description>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.name.dir</name>
        <value>/hadoop_data/datanode</value>
        <description>DataNode directory for storing data blocks</description>
    </property>

  <property>
      <name>dfs.replication</name>
      <value>1</value>
      <description>How many replicas of data blocks should exist in HDFS</description>
  </property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.journalnode.edits.dir</name>
  <value>/hadoop_data/journalnode/</value>
  <description>
    The directory where the journal edit files are stored.
  </description>
</property>
```

And core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://cluster</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

I'm following this guide: https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.2/bk_hadoop-high-availability/content/ha-nn-deploy-nn-cluster.html
The namenodes, datanodes, journalnodes, and YARN resource manager all run on separate containers on one local docker network. In the guide, I am forgoing setting up zookeeper, because I would just like to run the startup commands for both namenodes. When I try to run:

```
hdfs namenode -bootstrapStandby
```

I receive a ConnectionRefused error to the second namenode port: namenode2:8020. Here are my docker run commands:

```
docker run -d --net hadoop --net-alias namenode1 --name namenode1 -h namenode1 -p 50070:50070 "nn"
docker run -d --net hadoop --net-alias namenode2 --name namenode2 -h namenode1 -p 50070:50070 "nn"
```

Do I need to add the nameservices string "cluster" to my hostnames?

Comment: AFAIK, Zookeeper is required for leader election between the two Namenodes

Comment: I see. But is it necessary for syncing the two namenodes?